# index.js Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-class-static-block'

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs, react-native-webview, kaboom

I dont know what happened. I tried to implement Kaboom and then WebView. Both lead me to this error:

```
node_modules/react-native-webview/ index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-class-statick-block'
```

package.json (only the babel part)

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0", //only installed in case that solves the problem (it didn't)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0"
  },
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'babel-preset-env'], //babel-preset-env only installed because I thought it maybe solves the problem (it didn't)
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-transform-class-static-block',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block' //incase I wrote it wrong the first time
    ],
  };
};
```